# Cassandra status is Inactive

Tags: cassandra

please help with this how can i resolve this problem.
[image]

Comment: What at the jvm.options being used, how much memory is it being given?

Comment: @Andrew can you please tell how to check memory and what is jvm.options being used

Comment: There are a few places the options could be, jvm.options for example, using ps -a on the running process though is the most reliable way of seeing it - you would just have to be quick to do it that way before it dies.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I'd like to make a friendly request and ask that you paste the outputs in text instead of screenshots. A lot of the engineers who answer questions here respond during their free time on their mobile devices and screenshots are very difficult to read. It would make it easier to help you if you paste the text instead. For reference, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information you provided, all I can say is that the OOM killer terminated the Cassandra process.

The most common reason for this is that the server ran out of memory which triggered the OOM killer to terminate the process which is consuming the most RAM.

You need to either (a) allocate more RAM to the machine, or (b) make sure there is sufficient memory available for all the apps/processes running on the machine. Cheers!